# Для чего нужен unsigned char

Tags: c++, типы-данных

С unsigned int, unsigned long и другими unsigned числовыми типами все понятно - они для хранения беззнаковых целых, то в чем предназначение unsigned char? Для чего он обычно используется?

Comment: Так тоже для беззнаковых целых, только меньшего размера?

Comment: Пожалуйста, исправьте вопрос, чтобы он отражал конкретную проблему с достаточным количеством деталей для возможности дать адекватный ответ.

Answer (score 1):

Для хранения беззнаковых целых из 8 бит, в диапазоне значений 0-255.

Естественная форма представления *байта* (минимальной адресуемой памяти).